# Array element count in C

Tags: c, arrays, alignment

I've always used following paradigm for iterating over statically-defined arrays in C:

```
struct foo { ... };
struct foo array[10];

for (int i; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); i++)
    ...
```

And, well, this worked every time so far ;-)

But it makes wonder, could this not break if the struct was actually of length that doesn't align naturally, e.g.:

```
struct foo { long a; char b; };
```

Shouldn't the compiler decide that `sizeof(struct foo) == 7` while `sizeof(array) == 32` due to alignment (LP64 data model)?

Comment: I'm looking for a canonical reference if my assumption was true or a counter-example if my assumption doesn't always hold.

Comment: BTW is an integer division, it couldn't gives you wrong number. Am I wrong?

Comment: "_Shouldn't the compiler decide that `sizeof(struct foo) == 7`_" Not necessarily, there can be padding.

Comment: Your paradigm is intact, otherwise how would the compiler dereference indices into that array?

Comment: Note: You didn't initialize `i` in the given code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [C99 standard, section 6.5.3.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p4) states about `sizeof` operator:

> When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the
>   total number of bytes in the array.

And:

> EXAMPLE 2 Another use of the sizeof operator is to compute the number
>   of elements in an array:
>
> ```
>      `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`
> ```

So the size of array will *always* be a multiple of size of it's elements.

And from the same paragraph about structs:

> When applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the
>   result is the total number of bytes in such an object, including
>   internal and trailing padding.

Comment: Also from the standard: "When applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object, **including internal and trailing padding.**"

Answer (score 4):

No.

There is no "dead space" in an array; if there's padding, it's *included* in the `struct` size.

Comment: Looks like you are right on the money, I can tweak struct size with gcc's `__attribute__((packed))` and e.g. `__attribute__((aligned(128)))` but whatever I try to do to the array, it stays a const multiple of array.

Answer (score 2):

A structure intenal alignment of members do not have impact on an *array* of that structure. So irrespective what members a struct contains or how they are aligned, what you have is guaranteed to work.

*If* there's a padding between members of the struct, then it's the same for *all* the elements of the struct array. `sizeof(array)` is always evenly divisible by `sizeof(array[0])`.

So the method of calculating array size,

```
size_t len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

is guaranteed to work for *any* type as long as the `array` an *array*.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` macro returns the size of your struct *including* all the padding.  This remains true for a statically defined array of `struct`.  So the statement:

```
sizeof(struct array) / sizeof(struct array[0])
```

Will always allow you to iterate through the array elements regardless of how many or what type of members in each struct element.

*Packing/alignment makes no difference for array bounds*
Even if ***[pragma pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273913%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)*** directive is used in your source, possibly causing the packing to change (which can also affect alignment), resulting in a different value for sizeof for each struct element of your array, ***the count of array elements stays the same***.

*...or a counter-example if my assumption doesn't always hold*

*It is important to note*:
The `sizeof` operator works differently on *arrays* of struct (or any other type) that are actually pointers, dynamically created on the heap.  For example if you had:

```
typedef struct { ... }FOO; 
FOO *foo;
...
foo = malloc(10*sizeof(FOO));
size_t size = sizeof(foo); //returns sizeof pointer, (4 bytes on 32 bit target)
                           //No matter how many, or what type members make up the struct
```

*Therefore*

```
sizeof(struct foo) / sizeof(struct foo[0])
```

Will no longer give you the correct count of array elements.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is free to insert padding within the struct everywhere between the members and at its end, with the exception that the offset of the first member has to always be zero.

Arrays, on the other hand, always have to be contiguous without any "gaps" between the elements. The standard states that:

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects

Usually, most compilers will insert some padding at the end of the struct to make sure that when laid out contiguously in an array, the second element doesn't break the alignment requirements of some of the members. The typical rule is that the total size of the struct has to be extended to a size that is evenly divisible by the alignment of the member with the greatest alignment requirement.

In an LP64 model, `sizeof(long)` is 8 and `sizeof(char)` is 1. `long` would require 8-byte alignment, `char` has no alignment requirements. The sum of the sizes would be `9`, but the compiler would extend the size of the struct to 16, so that `16 % 8 == 0`. This way, an adjacent array element will start at a location that is evenly divisible by `8`, so the alignment of the first member will be preserved.